# Why do 'input' events not fire on file inputs, but 'change' events do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Testing a simple input:

```
<input type="file"/>
```

The `input` event does not fire when a new file is selected:

```
$('input').on('input', function(event){
    console.log('input value changed', event.target.value)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baLn0sfy/

The `change` event fires:

```
$('input').on('change', function(event){
    console.log('input value changed', event.target.value)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fzegLugd/

Why doesn't the 'input' event fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/number-state.html#file-upload-state), for a file input, "The input event does not apply." (see the last bullet under bookkeeping details).

Answer (score 0):

The [supported elements for the input event are limited to textArea,
input type=text, or input type=password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg592978(v=vs.85).aspx). From MSDN:

> Input event occurs when the text content of an element is changed
>   through the user interface.
>
> You can use the oninput to detect when the contents of a textArea,
>   input type=text, or input type=password have changed. This event
>   occurs immediately after modification, unlike the onchange event,
>   which occurs when the element loses focus.